# Output Bubble Sort results to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

Hi I have a bubble sort method that takes my array of strings and sorts them. However I want the sorted strings to be entered into another array so that the original unsorted array can be used for other things. Can anyone help me or guide me in the right direction? Thanks

The new array where I would like to store the strings is called myArray2
Heres my bubble sort code

```
    public static void sortStringBubble( String  x [ ] )
{
      int j;
      boolean flag = true;
      String temp;

      while ( flag )
      {
            flag = false;
            for ( j = 0;  j < x.length - 1;  j++ )
            {
                    if ( x [ j ].compareToIgnoreCase( x [ j+1 ] ) > 0 )
                    {                                             
                                temp = x [ j ];
                                x [ j ] = x [ j+1];     
                                x [ j+1] = temp;
                                flag = true;

                     }
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `System.arraycopy()` and than sort that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your method return a String[] rather than void.

```
public static String[] sortStringBubble( String  x [ ] )
   String[] copy = new String[x.length];
   System.arraycopy(x, 0, copy, 0, x.length);

   // do everything on the copy

   return copy;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it does work, but I cant get it to print in my JList object which is called print. I tried calling a new JList print(copy) but it didnt work

Comment: @jj007: It works fine with `JList`.Here is the way i tried `String[] temp = t.sortStringBubble(x);` than `JList list = new JList(temp)`. Here `t` is the object of class where `sortStringBubble` resides.

Answer (score 1):

Sure
1) Change the method signature to be String[]

```
public static String[] sortStringBubble( String[]  input  ) {
```

2) add a new String[] x

```
String[] x  = (String[])input.clone();
```

3) add a return x at the bottom

```
return x;
```

Comment: Sorry it does work, but I cant get it to print in my JList object which is called print. I tried calling a new JList print(x) but it didnt work